# Creating smart login/my account buttons

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables

How can I make my php website be able to tell if a user is logged in?

I want to show a link to "my account" instead of "Login".

EX. user goes to home page and clicks "login" on top right corner, then after logging in when browsing the home page again it will display "my account" instead of "login".

This is what the login button looks like. I want to be able to replace this with "my account" if a user is logged in.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xCDB.png

UPDATE: This is the code im attempting to use now. its giving me errors on lines 69/72

```
    <form action="scripts/login.php" id="login-form">
        <fieldset>
        <?php
       if(isset($_SESSION['name_of_user']))
       {
    **LINE 69** <a href="your_account.php" class="login" onClick="submit"><span><span>My Account</span></span></a><span class="links"><a href="reset-pwd-req.php">Forgot Password?</a><br/><a href="create_account.php">Register</a></span>     }
        } 
        else{
    **LINE 72**     <a href="general_login.php" class="login" onClick="submit"><span><span>Login</span></span></a><span class="links"><a href="reset-pwd-req.php">Forgot Password?</a><br/><a href="create_account.php">Register</a></span>     }
        ?>
```

Comment: Don't know why people are downvoting and not letting you know why. Its obvious what the question is, and (although it is "basic" php) if you don't know it then its perfectly valid to ask the question. Ignore the downvoters (especially the silent ones).

Comment: I agree; a perfectly valid question. I guess that the silent downvoters are those who do not know the answers themselves. :)

Answer (score 2):

So you need to use sessions to do this.

First of all you call this right at the top of your php file:

```
session_start();
```

To start the session, then you can set `$_SESSION` variables. When the user logs in you can set (for example):

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = "Lucas Weir";
```

Then on the next php script you can do:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
    // user is logged in, hide the button here
} else {
    // user is not logged in, show the login button
}
```

Sessions aren't complicated at all, but its worth looking into them. This is a very basic way of using sessions, but it isn't very secure at all. To be honest, I'm surprised you've managed to create a whole user login/authentication script without using sessions yet. ;)

Edit: a bit more info.

Sessions are stored on the server. They are "similar" to cookies. A session token is stored in a cookie on the client computer. This is then used to cross reference the session information stored on your server.

As the session token (Session id) is stored on the client computer, it can send it every time another one of your scripts loads. This means that when you set a session variable using `$_SESSION['name'] = "value";` the same value can be retrieved on the next script that gets called.

For a bit more information and some examples/tutorials have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Thanks a million ill try this out and look into that. :)

Comment: this is the code im using now with your recommendations but dreamweaver is giving me syntax errors on lines 69 and 72 look above

Comment: Inside PHP you have to echo the HTML

Comment: You can't just put HTML in PHP like that. You must close the PHP tags first. Do something like this: `<?php if(true) { ?><span>HTML Here (you've close the PHP tag)</span><?php } else { ?><span>Some more HTML here</span><?php } ?>`

Comment: @LucasWeir you're ok. :) its difficult when you don't know how what you're doing. You'll pick it up.

Comment: @Thomas I never though to break out of PHP in the middle of an if-statement.  That's why I love this site, I was trying to help and ended up learning something new myself.

Comment: @Gary you're welcome. :) I typed up a few examples to show you some more cool stuff you can use to make things easier/look better: http://pastebin.com/xq04DfU6 Hope that helps. :)